# how to pass a hostname as env var with rancher server

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rancher

I am using docker 1.12 and rancher server 1.5.9. I am trying to create a stack in rancher to deploy and orchestrate my app. My issue is that I need to pass as `env var` the hostname of the host where the container will be running.

Since I have only one image that will be used to create one kind of container on several host (let's say 2 for the tests) I can't pass it like `HOSTNAME=myhostname`. The value needs to be a `var` which will be set with the docker host.

Does anyone know how to do that with the rancher server UI?
Does anyone know how rancher retrieve the hostname when adding a custom host?

Can we use the entry point or CMD to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Having an `/etc/hosts` on the machine that prioritizes the desired name over `localhost` helped in my case. Obviously, also have an `/etc/hostname` that agrees with `/etc/hosts`.

I am using container linux. So for me, it looks like so in the ct-config before converting to ignition.

```
storage:
  files:
    - filesystem: "root"
      path:       "/etc/hostname"
      mode:       0644
      contents:
        inline: ${hostname}
    - filesystem: "root"
      path:       "/etc/hosts"
      mode:       0644
      contents:
        inline:  "127.0.0.1 ${hostname} localhost\n
                 ::1 ${hostname} localhost"
```

Just be sure to have the above before you run the rancher registration line.

```
sudo docker run --rm --privileged \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ 
-v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher \
rancher/agent:v1.2.7 https://myrancher/v1/scripts/TOKEN
```